# How to represent and track mutable state in a text-adventure game (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

This question is about how to design an app, and layout data, to represent mutable state in an  adventure game where there are locations the player can be in, and items which can either be in those locations, or in the players inventory after they pick them up.

```
newtype ItemName     = ItemName Text
newtype LocationName = LocationName Text
newtype Description  = Description Text
new type ItemWeight  = ItemWeight Int

data Location = Location LocationName Description [Item]
data Item     = Item ItemName [ItemName] Description ItemWeight
data Player   = Player PlayerPosition [Item]

data PlayerPosition = ...
```

It may not make sense for each `Location` to have a list of `Item`s, since this is mutable, and everything else is immutable. Likewise for `Player`

In such a game the core logic falls into a function called.

```
playMove :: Move -> GameState -> ([MoveResult], GameState)
```

where the `Move` and `MoveResult` functions are

```
data Move                              data MoveResult
  = MoveTo Direction                     = EnteredLocation Location
  | PickUpItem ItemName                  | NoLocationAt Direction
  | UseItemWithItem ItemName ItemName    | PickedUpItem Item
  | Examine ItemName                     | UsedItemWithItem Item
  | Quit                                 | CantUseItems Item Item
                                         | NoSuchItem Item
                                         | Description Item
                                         | InventoryFull ItemWeight Item
                                         | GameWon
                                         | ...
```

Parsing user input into `Move` values, and outputting the `MoveResult`s, is something that happens in the IO monad. Direction is just a sum-type over `North | South | East | West`

Most of these will no doubt involve a `GameState` which captures

1. The player position in the world
2. The contents of their inventory
3. Where the items are located. Items may be in a location, in the player's inventory, or in limbo. Items in limbo have not yet been created by combining items, or having been erased in the combining them.

My question is

1. What is a good data-structure to represent the `GameState`. Such a structure should encapsulate the player's position and inventory contents, and where items may be found in the world. It should faciliate an API like

   - `moveTo :: GameState -> Direction -> ([MoveResult], GameState)` where the `MoveResult` is either `EnteredLocation` or `NoLocationAt`. This in turn requires a function like `locationAt :: Location -> Direction -> Maybe Location`
   - `pickUp :: GameState -> ItemName -> ([MoveResult], GameState)` where the `MoveResult` is `PickedUpItem` or `NoSuchItem`. In this case how does one match `ItemName` to an `Item`
   - `useItemWithItem :: GameState -> (ItemName, ItemName) -> ([MoveResult], GameState)` where the `MoveResult` is either `PickedUpItem` if a new items results, or `CantUserItems` otherwise. This in turn requires a function like `combineItems :: Item -> Item -> Maybe Item` to see if items can be combined.
2. What is a good data-structure to represent `PlayerPosition`
3. Should I use heavy `Location` types or introduce some LocationId in representing the `PlayerPosition` and potentially the items positions
4. For the graph mapping origin `Location` to destination `Location` via a `Direction` edge, what is the best data-structure to use. I was thinking a `Data.Map` of `(Location, Direction)` to `Location`.

I am aware of zippers, and the the fact that `playMove` fits into the `State` monad. My issue is how to structure `GameState` to capture the mutable and immutable parts of this problem.

---

## Edit: The Answer

I did find an answer from this productive [discussion on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/4aasm6/question_how_to_represent_state_in_a/). In case anyone else finds this question, [/u/achadoseperdidos](https://www.reddit.com/user/achadoseperdidos) in that discussion pointed out that the answer to my question is provided by [chapter 11 of Learn PureScript by Example](https://leanpub.com/purescript/read#leanpub-auto-monadic-adventures) which actually describes how to use the RWS monads to write an adventure game - exactly the answer I was seeking.

Comment: The question is pretty open-ended, I think it should be moved to: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'd argue it's actually fairly specific. The world is defined. So are the actions and their results, and the datatypes necessary to describe them. What's needed is a definition of a `GameState to encapsulate the world, in its mutable and immutable parts, and define how it to implement the named methods above. It's a design rather than a coding question, I agree, but purely functional design of applications classes is a valid question.

Comment: @Feenaboccles If your code compiles *and* it does what you want it to, then your question is for codereview **not** for StackOverflow. SO questions **must** contain an actual **problem** in their statement: e.g. runtime or compile time error, wrong output, crash etc.  Things like "what's the best way to do this" and "how to improve the style/efficiency/robustness of this code" are *off topic*.

Comment: @Bakuriu, I think there's a fuzzy line. This question, however, is not focused enough for SO.

Comment: Good God lads, read the question. I am asking what is a suitable data structure to represent game-state in a purely functional language, and how should the given operations be implemented given that structure. It is a design question, rather than a coding question, but that is no reason to dump it into code-review. Indeed, it should be clear that since I have no `GameState` implementation, as I'm asking what it should be, that I have no code that compiles.

Comment: To "capture the mutable and immutable parts of this problem" you could use the `RWS` monad, which is a state monad with a read-only and read-write component.

Comment: You can and should answer your own question instead of writing the answer into the question. In the future, please note that being rude to people is not an effective way to get your questions answered. Some people around here are seasoned programmers or researchers or women and probably don't appreciate "Come on, lads!"

Comment: @dfeuer I can't answer the question, it's been closed, so to be helpful, I made the edit. Wrt your mention of women and my use of "lads" you, Bakuriu and utdemir are all male, so that implicit criticism is irrelevant. Wrt to rudeness, I made no no personal attacks, only an expression of exasperation when Bakuriu, not understanding the question, told me to just run a program I hadn't even designed yet. Experience didn't help there. Bear in mind my only answer at that point was the unhelpful "Use zippers". I still made the effort to address the criticism by re-writing the question.

Answer (score 0):

At this scale, you need not worry about size or efficiency. Simply use a record like:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

data Location = Location
  { locationname :: String
  , description :: String
  } deriving Ord

data GameStep = GameStep
  { itemsWorld :: M.Map Location [Item]
  , inventory :: [Item]
  , position :: Location
  }
```

Comment: That still doesn't really answer the question of how to mutate all these